# Need Pyramid Chart Graph Using Highchart.js library

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I Need a Pyramid Chart Graph Using Highchart.js library, same as like attached image. Can anyone please suggest?

[image]

Comment: Took me a single minute to go through their demos: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/polar-spider

Comment: Why not write some code to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use area series on a polar chart with polygon grid line interpolation. Example:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        polar: true,
        type: 'area'
    },
    yAxis: {
        gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
        lineWidth: 0,
        tickInterval: 1,
        min: 1,
        max: 10
    },
    ...
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/v8rgunaf/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.gridLineInterpolation